# How to delimit both "=" and "==" in Java when reading

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to output both "==" and "=" as tokens.

For example, the input text file is:

```
biscuit==cookie apple=fruit+-()
```

The output:

```
biscuit
=
=
cookie
apple
=
fruit
+
-
(
)
```

What I want the output to be:

```
biscuit
==
cookie
apple
=
fruit
+
-
(
)
```

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
        s.useDelimiter("\\s|(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct})");

        while (s.hasNext()) {

            String next = s.next();
            System.out.println(next);
       }
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Edit: I want to be able to keep the current regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to qualify those punctuations with some additional assertions.

```
 # "\\s|(?<===)|(?<=\\p{Punct})(?!(?<==)(?==))|(?=\\p{Punct})(?!(?<==)(?==))"

   \s 
|  (?<= == )
|  (?<= \p{Punct} )
   (?!
        (?<= = )
        (?= = )
   )
|  (?= \p{Punct} )
   (?!
        (?<= = )
        (?= = )
   )
```

*Info update*

If some characters aren't covered in `\p{Punct}` just add them as a separate class within
the punctuation subexpressions.

For engines that don't do certain properties well inside classes, use this ->

```
 #  Raw:   \s|(?<===)|(?<=\p{Punct}|[=+])(?!(?<==)(?==))|(?=\p{Punct}|[=+])(?!(?<==)(?==))

    \s 
 |  (?<= == )
 |  (?<= \p{Punct} | [=+] )
    (?!
         (?<= = )
         (?= = )
    )
 |  (?= \p{Punct} | [=+] )
    (?!
         (?<= = )
         (?= = )
    )
```

For engines that handle properties well inside classes, this is a better one ->

```
 #  Raw:   \s|(?<===)|(?<=[\p{Punct}=+])(?!(?<==)(?==))|(?=[\p{Punct}=+])(?!(?<==)(?==))

    \s 
 |  (?<= == )
 |  (?<= [\p{Punct}=+] )
    (?!
         (?<= = )
         (?= = )
    )
 |  (?= [\p{Punct}=+] )
    (?!
         (?<= = )
         (?= = )
    )
```

Comment: accepted this answer because it's both correct and the shortest solution. thank you sir.

Comment: @vks it works in my program.. with the exact same input

Comment: @vks That is why I don't like answers on Java questions which are linked to examples in regex101 or other sites where you can't chose regex engine from Java explicitly. Only because something works on regex101 doesn't mean that it will also work in Java (negation is also true, if somethinng doesn't work in regex101 doesn't mean it will also not work in Java).

Comment: @vks Could it be that it doesn't recognize `\p{Punct}` ? If you try puttin in `\\s|(?<=\\p{Punct})` it doesn't do what it should

Comment: @Pshemo but what could be the reason........all features are supported by java right???jut additional escaping ?

Comment: @Codemon changed punct to `\p{P}`

Comment: @vks same result. Pshemo is probably right. regex101 must have completely different syntax for some or none at all. Bottom line is that it works for my program and I'm happy :D woohoo!

Comment: @vks It seems that `\p{Punct}` in Java represents `[!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~]`. If you use this class instead of `\p{P}` you will get correct results. I am not sure what `\p{P}` stands for in Java or regex101.

Answer (score 5):

Just split the input string according to the below regex .

```
String s = "biscuit==cookie apple=fruit"; 
String[] tok = s.split("\\s+|\\b(?==+)|(?<==)(?!=)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

**Output:**

```
[biscuit, ==, cookie, apple, =, fruit]
```

**Explanation:**

- `\\s+` Matches one or more space characters.
- `|` OR
- `\\b(?==+)` Matches a word boundary only if it's followed by a `=` symbol.
- `|` OR
- `(?<==)` Lookafter to `=` symbol.
- `(?!=)` And match the boundary only if it's not followed by a `=` symbol.

**Update:**

```
String s = "biscuit==cookie apple=fruit+-()"; 
String[] tok = s.split("\\s+|(?<!=)(?==+)|(?<==)(?!=)|(?=[+()-])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

**Output:**

```
[biscuit, ==, cookie, apple, =, fruit, +, -, (, )]
```

Comment: you mean like this? `s.useDelimiter("\\s|(?=[\\s=]+)|(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct})");` ? I want to be able to keep what I did here.

Comment: But I need to be able to output tokens such as separators (`; ] )` ) and operators ( `+ - %`) as separate from the string and if I add your regex to mine it doesn't work.

Comment: post an example which reflect the above comment.

Comment: sorry but I found better answer. may be I should be more patient. I know you are an expert  but please have explanation so I can learn from you. +1 for added explanation :)

Comment: Yes it works! But I'm going to have to go with the last answer to this question as it is a shorter solution which fits because I have  lots of separators and operators. Thank you sir. +1

Answer (score 2):

In other words you want to split on

1. one or more whitespaces
2. place which has `=` after it and non-`=` before it (like `foo|=` where `|` represents this place)
3. place which has `=` before it it and non-`=` after it (like `=|foo` where `|` represents this place)

In other words

```
s.useDelimiter("\\s+|(?<!=)(?==)|(?<==)(?!=)");
//             ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
//cases:         1)        2)        3)
```

Since it looks like you are building parser I would suggest using tool which will let you build correct grammar like http://www.antlr.org/. But if you must stick with regex then other improvement which will let you build regex easier would be using `Matcher#find` instead of delimiter from Scanner. This way your regex and code could look like

```
    String data = "biscuit==cookie apple=fruit+-()";

    String regex = "<=|==|>=|[\\Q<>+-=()\\E]|[^\\Q<>+-=()\\E]+";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
biscuit
==
cookie apple
=
fruit
+
-
(
)
```

You can make this regex more general by using

```
String regex = "<=|==|>=|\\p{Punct}|\\P{Punct}+";
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^-- standard cases
//              ^^ ^^ ^^------------------------- special cases
```

Also this approach would require reading data from file first, and storing it in single String which you would parse. You can find many ways of how to read text from file for instance in this question: 
[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

so you can use something like

```
String data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input.txt")));
```

You can specify encoding which String should use while reading bytes from file by using constructor `String(bytes, encoding)`. So you can write it as `new String(butes,"UTF-8")` or to avoid typos while selecting encoding use one of stored in `StandardCharsets` class like `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: @Pshemo See my edited question. If I add your regex to mine it doesn't work. I need to be able to edit it such that all that I've done so far remains.

Comment: @Codemon It looks like you are trying to create parser with regex. If so then regex is not the best approach. You should be using grammar tool like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) instead. Anyway I will try to update my answer but that will be the last one (if you will have any other requests about regex and parser then it is sign that you should definitely use grammar instead of regex).

Comment: @Pshemon This is part of my homework and I am requested to use regex

Comment: @Codemon Is scanner obligatory also? I would say that using `Matcher.find` would be easier than setting delimiter.

Comment: Well I am reading from a file, I'm not quite sure how to read it otherwise

Comment: while this is an excellent answer, I used \p{Punct} because I have a lot of separators and operators I need to take into consideration. I have found a shorter solution on the answer below yours. +1 for excellent explanation .

Answer (score 0):

```
(?===)|(?<===)|\s|(?<!=)(?==)|(?<==)(?!=)|(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})|(?=\+)
```

You can try this.Se demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/18